# Как вывести список в две строки одним вызовом функции print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно ли вывести подобный список в две строки не вызывая два раза print()?

```
print('Строк: ', len(a), ';', ' Столбцов: ', len(a[0]), '.', sep='')
```

чтобы получилось в две строки:

Строк: *len(a)*;
Столбцов: *len(a[0])*.

а не в одну:

Строк: *len(a)*; Столбцов: *len(a[0])*.

Comment: `\r\n` добавьте после `;`

Comment: @LamerXaKer Спасибо!

Comment: @LamerXaKer: Python использует универсальный режим строк по умолчанию, поэтому следует `'\n'` использовать, а не `'\r\n'`.

Comment: @jfs как я понял '\r\n' используется чтобы строки корректно переносились в среде Windows. Для Unix-систем достаточно '\n'

Comment: @SergeyMokhin : нет. Питон самостоятельно `\n` в `os.linesep` преобразует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для разделения строк вполне подходит символ `\n`. Достаточно поставить его в то место, где нужен перенос строки.

---

Ещё хотел заметить, что нагляднее использовать соответствующие возможности Python для форматированного вывода, например, форматирующий метод:

```
print('Строк: {};\nСтолбцов: {}.'.format(len(a), len(a[0])))
```

Так сразу становится понятнее структура записываемой информации.

Можно даже записать так:

```
print('Строк: {};\n'
      'Столбцов: {}.'.format(len(a), len(a[0])))
```

Иногда используют оператор форматирования строки `%`:

```
print('Строк: %s;\n'
      'Столбцов: %s.' % (len(a), len(a[0])))
```

Запись с его использованием, в основном, короче, но может быть менее понятной.

Comment: примеры, где код разбит на несколько строк, выглядели бы лучше в виде отдельных `print()` вызовов: `print('Строк:', nrows)`...

Answer (score 0):

Попытайся юзать  "\n". Должно сработать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Строк: ', len(a), ';', '\nСтолбцов: ', len(a[0]))
```